Plotting interaction by logistic regression
I have used R to plot the interaction term from the logit function I computed.
I use the standard cat_plot() to plot the interaction. I clearly see that the two lines are NOT parallel, it's pretty obvious (but they are not crossing over either).
But the P value for the interaction term is 0.079.
How should I interpret this? Can I still assume that there is an interaction, but it's not significant?
I might think that the reason why it's not significant, is due to the rarity of the moderator in my sample. Could that be the reason?

The "lines" represent the estimates, and the p-value on the interaction is a formal test of whether the interaction is present. Remember that just by sampling error, the lines will differ even when there isn't an interaction. You cannot distinguish your results from such a scenario.

Thanks for answering, but what if, in a second scenario were the the lines are crossing, but the P value is still not significant?

@Noah by switching the variables (the predictor and the putative moderator), the lines crossed. That ofc changes my research question too, but would it still be valid, to assume that the previous predictor is maybe the moderator now? even though the p value is not significant

it's quite common that an interaction is not statistically significant even when the slopes are non-parallel or even cross. This may be because there's actually no interaction or because of small N (or for other reasons too). You shouldn't change your research questions after looking at the results, that's data dredging / p-hacking and gives you unreliable results.

@DeviSita What I'm saying is that just because you observed something in your sample, doesn't mean it is occurring in the population. That's the whole reason we use significance tests in the first place. If you ignore p-values and treat any pattern you see in the data seriously, you will always find effects and relationships even when none exist in the population.
